# Iterm2 case insensitive autocomplete

Tags: terminal, iterm2

How can I add case insensitive autocomplete to Iterm2 terminal? I have tried:

```
set completion-ignore-case on
```

But this does not seem to be the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was entering in the `set completion-ignore-case on` as a command in the command line. I instead needed to navigate to my root directory, create a file named `.inputrc` and input the `set completion-ignore-case on` text in that file.

Comment: use ```zsh```, that's a default setting :)

Answer (score 16):

Set ignore case on in inputrc file. The following command will create the file with the command if not exist already

```
echo "set completion-ignore-case On" >> ~/.inputrc
```

Then run

```
source ~/.inputrc
```

to load it on current instance of terminal.